# mod_rewrite and already indexed pages

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, search-engine

I have a PHP page, lets say `/users/profile.php`, and I need to make the URL more elegant, like `/users/123` instead of `/users/profile.php?id=123`.
I defined the needed rule, that on `/users/123` executes the `/users/profile.php?id=123` with the following:

```
RewriteRule ^users/([0-9]+)$ /users/profile.php?id=$1 [L]
```

and everything works perfect, but search engines already familiar with the `/users/profile.php?id=123` page.
How do I guide them, or any other users to switch to `/users/123` when they ask for `/profile.php?id=123`?

Just to make sure, I need this to be done:

1. User asks for `/profile.php?id=123`
2. User is redirected to `/users/123` with 301 status code
3. The server executes `/profile.php?id=123` and returns the HTML to the user

Comment: `<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/users/123" />` in html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.htaccess` with:

```
RewriteRule ^users/(\d+)/?$ /users/profile.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(\d+)$
RewriteRule ^users/profile\.php$ /users/%1 [R=301,L]
```

And to avoid loop, I would change the name of the page that normally no one needs to know (profile.php -> profileNEW.php)

Comment: There are loops in this way. I checked it more, and the only way is to rename the (hidden..) PHP page.

Comment: It's not the only way, but it seems to me that this is the easiest in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id\=(\d+)
RewriteRule ^users/profile\.php$ /users/%1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need two rules:

Externally redirect `/users/profile.php?id=123` to `/users/123`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^/users/profile\.php$ /user/%1 [R=307,L]
```

Internally forward `/user/123` to `/users/profile.php`:

```
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9]+)$ /users/profile.php?id=$1 [L]
```

I changed the `/users` to `/user`, since the URL describes a single user.

(This is all from memory, without actual testing. But the basic idea is the `[R=307]` flag in the first rule.)

Comment: You’ll probably want to use 301 (Moved Permanently) instead of 307 (Temporary Redirect).